# Can't access public non-static class attribute from secondary class

Tags: java

I have the following two classes:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1 randomvariable; // Variable declared

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        randomvariable = new Class1(); // Variable initialized
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public static void ranMethod()
    {
        randomvariable.getSomething(); // I can't access the member "randomvariable" here even though it's public and it's in the same project?
    }
}
```

I am very certain that it's a very fundamental thing I'm missing here, but what am I actually missing? The Class1 member "randomvariable" is public and so is the class and both classes are in the same project.
What do I have to do to fix this problem?

Comment: I'd rather suggest to read some java tutorials to understand basics of OOP.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems:

Firstly, you're trying to assign a value to `randomvariable` from `main`, without there being an instance of `Class1`. This would be okay in an instance method, as `randomvariable` would be implicitly `this.randomvariable` - but this is a static method.

Secondly, you're trying to read the value from `Class2.ranMethod`, again without there being an instance of `Class1` involved.

It's important that you understand what an instance variable is. It's a value associated with a particular instance of a class. So if you had a class called `Person`, you might have a variable called `name`. Now in `Class2.ranMethod`, you'd effectively be writing:

```
name.getSomething();
```

That makes no sense - firstly there's nothing associating this code with `Person` at all, and secondly it doesn't say *which* person is involved.

Likewise within the `main` method - there's no instance, so you haven't got the context.

Here's an alternative program which *does* work, so you can see the difference:

```
public class Person {
    // In real code you should almost *never* have public variables
    // like this. It would normally be private, and you'd expose
    // a public getName() method. It might be final, too, with the value
    // assigned in the constructor.
    public String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person x = new Person();
        x.name = "Fred";
        PersonPresenter.displayPerson(x);
    }
}

class PersonPresenter {

    // In a real system this would probably be an instance method
    public static void displayPerson(Person person) {
        System.out.println("I present to you: " + person.name);
    }
}
```

As you can tell by the comments, this still isn't ideal code - but I wanted to stay fairly close to your original code.

However, this now works: `main` is trying to set the value of an instance variable *for a particular instance*, and likewise `presentPerson` is given a reference to an instance as a parameter, so it can find out the value of the `name` variable *for that instance*.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to access `randomvariable` you have to specify where it lives. Since its a non-static class field, you need an instance of `Class1` in order to have a `randomvariable`. For instance:

```
Class1 randomclass;
randomclass.randomvariable.getSomething();
```

If it were a static field instead, meaning that only one exists per class instead of one per instance, you could access it with the class name:

```
Class1.randomvariable.getSomething();
```